# Python, WMI, the registry, and strange results

Tags: python, windows, registry, wmi, pywin32

I need to create a python script to go through the contents of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and return the `DisplayName` of each key.

I'm using this as a starting ground (found on another stack-overflow post)

```
import _winreg
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI(namespace="default").StdRegProv

result, value = c.GetStringValue (
    hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    sSubKeyName="SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MRxDAV",
    sValueName="ImagePath"
)
print value
```

That works. It returns:

```
\SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mrxdav.sys
```

However, if I change the `sSubKeyName` and `sValueName` (to valid values), it appears to be extremely flaky, returning `None` more often than not.

For example:

```
c = wmi.WMI(namespace="default").StdRegProv

result, value = c.GetStringValue (
    hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{0E5D76AD-A3FB-48D5-8400-8903B10317D3}",
    sValueName="DisplayName"
)
print value
```

This results in `None` being printed.

However,

```
result, value = c.GetStringValue (
    hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer",
    sValueName="InstallerLocation"
)
print value
```

Returns the correct value,

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
```

If we then try:

```
result, value = c.GetStringValue (
    hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OptimalLayout",
    sValueName="LayoutFilePath"
)
print value
```

Returns `None`

I've tried raw strings and escaping the slashes, neither have worked. I've also tried the `GetExpandedString()` method and it behaves identically.

It appears to fail with longer `sSubKeyName` values, but this is just a gut feeling.

**EDIT**

Slightly cleaner version of the code posted by [Y__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667433/y)

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90140000-001F-040C-1000-0000000FF1CE}",
    0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)

name = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "DisplayName")
print name[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at your code and noticed that when it fails, the return code is `2` which means `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=3Dvs.%2085%29.aspx)

And indeed, for some reason, what I see using `regedit` and what I see with this code snippet are inconsistent :

```
err_code, results = c.EnumKey (
    hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
)
print err_code
for r in results:
    print result
```

I'm looking to find a proper explanation for this behavior.

Hope it helps,

Best

**EDIT**

I think that I've found the culprit thanks to this post (http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-February/008865.html).

So if you use the Python API to open the key you may fetch your data as needed.
Here is a small (ugly) code that should do the trick :

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{0E5D76AD-A3FB-48D5-8400-8903B10317D3}" ,
     0,
    _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY

i = 0
while True:
    try:
        name, val, key_type = _winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
        if name == "DisplayName":
            print "%s => %s" % (name, val)
        except:
            # No more indices
            break
        i += 1
```

Additional reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=VS.85).aspx

**EDIT 2**

Following your comment, here is a code snippet that should do what you want :

```
import _winreg

def getKeys(hKey, sSubKey):
    with _winreg.OpenKey(hKey, sSubKey, 0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)     as key:
        idx = 0
        while True:
            try:
                yield _winreg.EnumKey(key, idx)
            except:
                # No more indices
                break
            idx += 1

hKey = _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
sSubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"
for keyName in getKeys(hKey, sSubKey):
    with _winreg.OpenKey(hKey, "\\".join([sSubKey, keyName]) , 0, _winreg.KEY_READ |     _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY) as key:
        i = 0
        while True:
            try:
                name, val, key_type = _winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
                if name == "DisplayName":
                    print "%s\\%s => %s" % (keyName, name, val)
                    break
            except:
                break

            i += 1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Would it be possible to iterate over the Uninstall keys to find the DisplayName for all subkeys? I had a look at the docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) and couldn't find a way to make the other methods work with the flags apart from CreateKeyEx. Using EnumKey to feed keys into your code doesn't appear to work (file not found), I suspect due to it grabbing values from the 32bit view.

Comment: Please not that this code is just an example of what you could do.
Especially, I didn't found a better way than using `try` - `except` to iterate over the keys & values...

Comment: Awesome, I tried a few different approaches but couldn't get it working. I'll have to spend some time learning how yours works, thank you!